# Guice FactoryModuleBuilder an instance with constructor parameters

Tags: java, guice

I´m using Guice to initalize a class with some arguments from a config file

```
@Provides
@Singleton
RetryServiceCaller provideMaxRetryAttempts(@Named("config") JsonObject config) throws IOException {
    JsonObject retryDetails = config.getJsonObject("retry_details");
    return new RetryServiceCaller(retryDetails.getInteger("maxRetryAttempts"), retryDetails.getInteger("upperBoundary"), retryDetails.getInteger("lowerBoundary"),
                                  retryDetails.getLong("multiplicationFactor"), retryDetails.getInteger("timeout"), retryDetails.getInteger("increaseTimeout"));
}
```

This class is injected in another class which is singleton as well.

```
class A{
   @Inject private RetryServiceCaller retryServiceCaller;
}
```

But now the problem is that since this new class A is singleton, I need to clone the retryServiceCaller every time that somebody use this class A.

I´ve been investigating FactoryModuleBuilder to use it and create a factory for this class. But since the class has parameters from the config file I could not find the way to make it works.

Something like this

```
  class A{
       @Inject private RetryServiceCaller.Factory retryServiceCallerFactory;

   }
```

Then in my RetryServiceCaller implement this

```
public interface Factory {
    @Inject
    RetryServiceCaller create();
}


@Inject
public RetryServiceCaller(int maxRetryAttempts, int upperBoundary, int lowerBoundary, long multiplicationFactor, int timeout, int incrementTimeout) {
    this.maxRetryAttempts = maxRetryAttempts;
    this.upperBoundary = upperBoundary;
    this.lowerBoundary = lowerBoundary;
    this.multiplicationFactor = multiplicationFactor;
    this.timeout = timeout;
    this.incrementTimeout = incrementTimeout;
}
```

But guice throw me errors saying

```
No implementation for com.proxy.handlers.RetryServiceCaller$Factory was bound
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guice can automatically provide a zero-argument factory: Instead of injecting `Foo`, you can always inject `Provider<Foo>`. This allows you to call `fooProvider.get()` to create an instance whenever and wherever you'd like. You don't have to bind to a `Provider` or use a `Provides` method to get access to this; you can inject `Foo` or `Provider<Foo>` whether you use a `bind(...).to(...)` type binding, a `toProvider` binding, a `toInstance` binding, a `@Provides` method, or anything else, and Guice will call `get` or return an internal `Provider` automatically.

(The returned Provider will also respect scopes, so you'll need to drop your `@Singleton` scope in order to get more than one instance, and be aware that `toInstance` bindings will *always* return the same instance.)

This is not a job for FactoryModuleBuilder; only use FactoryModuleBuilder when you need to *mix injected and non-injected constructor parameters in the same type*.

Your finished binding should look like this:

```
@Provides
/* NOT @Singleton */
RetryServiceCaller provideMaxRetryAttempts(@Named("config") JsonObject config) throws IOException {
    JsonObject retryDetails = config.getJsonObject("retry_details");
    return new RetryServiceCaller(retryDetails.getInteger("maxRetryAttempts"), retryDetails.getInteger("upperBoundary"), retryDetails.getInteger("lowerBoundary"),
                                  retryDetails.getLong("multiplicationFactor"), retryDetails.getInteger("timeout"), retryDetails.getInteger("increaseTimeout"));
}
```

And in your class:

```
@Inject public YourCallerConsumer(Provider<RetryServiceCaller> callerProvider) {
  this.callerProvider = callerProvider;
}

public void doAction() {
  RetryServiceCaller newCaller = callerProvider.get();
  // interact with caller
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach should work just fine. If you don't want the `RetryServiceCaller` to be a singleton, remove the `@Singleton` annotation from the provider method, and a new instance will be created for every injection point.

Assisted inject could work here too, but it's overkill. If you want to go that route:

```
interface RetryServiceCallerFactory {
  RetryServiceCaller create(String configParam1, String configParam2);
}

public class RetryServiceCaller {
  @AssistedInject
  public RetryServiceCaller(String configParam1, String configParam2) {}
}
```

then, in your module

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(Factory.class);
```

and in your injection points

```
@Inject RetryServiceCallerFactory factory;

RetryServiceCaller create(JsonObject config) {
  return factory.create(config.getFirstParam(), config.getSecondParam());
}
```

You can refer to the [documentation](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryModuleBuilder.html) for more extensive examples.