# Implementing a factory which returns objects based on value

Tags: java, guice

I intend to do as follows-

```
public Car CarFactory {
    Car createCar(String carType) {
        if(carType.equals("abc"))
            return new ABCCar();
        if(carType.equals("def"))
            return new DEFCar();
        //so on...
    }
}
```

How can I achieve it using guice 4.0? Is FactoryModuleBuilder right candidate for it?

Answer (score 0):

We are missing some additional information here, the key point here is how do you plan to use CarFactory.

If this is the classic use case when you get some string and based on that string (or any other key) provided by the client you need to make a decision. That’s your own business logic and Guice isn’t the tool here.
If you don’t like the classic if-else way of factory pattern google for alternatives.

In case you know in your code which type of car you need in advance so Guice Provider is typed and you can define two providers for `Provider<ABCCar>` and for `Provider<ABCCar>`.

Use FactoryModuleBuilder when you need to mix injected and non-injected constructor parameters in the same type. See [Guice FactoryModuleBuilder an instance with constructor parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36290073/guice-factorymodulebuilder-an-instance-with-constructor-parameters)